# Convert StarUML diagram to Visio drawing

Tags: uml, visio, class-diagram, staruml

I have a class diagram which i created using Star Uml but now the requirement is to port it to MS Visio . Is it possible to port the .uml to a .vsd with the xml information available?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both programs support export/import of Windows Metafile (WMF) and Enhanced Windows Metafile (EMF). So you may try those.

Comment: My version of StarUML (macOS 3.2.2) doesn't seem to support export to (Enhanced/) Windows Metafile.  I only have Fragment, HTML Docs, PNG, JPG, and SVG...

Answer (score 3):

Exporting as a Windows Metafile (WMF) and Enhanced Windows Metafile (EMF) only imports to Visio as an image.

I understood that the purpose of exporting from StarUML and importing into Visio was being able to manipulate in Visio each one of the objects created in StarUML (e.g. classes).

I haven't found a solution for doing this.

Comment: I am also searching for a similar solution.

I am working in StarUML and I want to convert my StarUML class diagram to MS Visio 2016 class diagram. StarUML gives a great facility to reuse the classes in multiple diagrams under a package. It stores reference of the Class (Model Explorer) used in one diagram, that can be reused.

Can I do a similar thing in MS Visio after importing the respective SVG file from StartUML?

Answer (score 1):

Exporting from StarUML as a Windows Metafile (WMF) or Enhanced Windows Metafile (EMF) and then import to Visio as a grouped shape. 
It might look as an image at first look, but actually its a grouped shape. In order to edit, all you need to do is Right click on the grouped shape and "**Ungroup**".