# Convert StarUML class diagram to MS Visio class diagram

Tags: uml, visio, class-diagram

I am working with StarUML and I want to convert my StarUML class diagram to MS Visio 2016 class diagram. I am using MS Visio 2016 Professional.

I exported my class diagram as a *.emf* file from StarUML and tried to import it into MS Visio but I get an error "***The metafile cannot be placed***". But when I open this .emf file directly, it opens properly in MS Paint.

**Question**- How to get rid of the error "The metafile cannot be placed"?

Note: Exporting the class diagram from StarUML in *.svg* format & importing this *.svg* file works in Visio but it imports as a graphics image. But it is of no use since, since I cannot treat this image as a class diagram in Visio.

StarUML gives a great facility to reuse the classes in multiple diagrams under a package. It stores reference of the Class (Model Explorer) used in one diagram, that can be reused. 
So, When I modify attribute of class in one diagram, it is updated in the other diagrams where this class is reused.

**Question**- Can I do a similar thing in MS Visio after importing the respective SVG file from StartUML?

Comment: Just curious: why would you do that? Going from a modeling to a painting tool will do you no good for sure.

Comment: There is no useful way to import into Visio. All you will get is an image of your diagram, nothing more than that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert StarUML diagram to Visio drawing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9310425/convert-staruml-diagram-to-visio-drawing)